# How to Download a File in Flutter web Without Opening a New Tab Using js.context.callMethod('open', [zip, '_blank'])?

Tags: javascript, flutter

I'm currently working on a flutter web project where I need to download a file without opening a new tab. I've been experimenting with js.context.callMethod('open', [zip, '_blank']), which does download the file but in a new tab. However, I need the file to be downloaded within the current tab.

Here's the code snippet I've been using:

using his package,
https://pub.dev/packages/js/install

```
 js.context.callMethod('open', [zip, '_blank']);
```

Comment: js.context.callMethod('open', [zip, '_self']);
it works fine!.